# Div element animation while scrolling

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, delay

I have multiple `<div class="box">` (one for every part of the page, example one for slideshow, one for news and so on) that slides up on windows load, but what I want to do exactly is that it start to slide up,with a delay of 2 seconds,  when the user scroll the page and the section is visible to the user.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.box').addClass('boxload');
});
```

as you can see when the windows loads it add a css class that it make the div slide up, I can see the first element but when I scroll, ofcourse, the others `div class="box"` are already up, and I want that those others start the slide when the section appear on screen.
The css

```
    .box {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  top: 95px;
  background: #E0563B;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 6;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000000, inset 0 -1px 3px #000000;
}
.boxload{
    position:relative !important;
    top:45px !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Any suggestions?

I tried this

```
$("#last-post").scroll(function(){
$('.box').addClass('boxload');
});
```

but is not working...

Comment: Can you show some code, what have you tried so far ? And how you are sliding up the div elements ?

Comment: the div elements are sliding up just by adding a class                  $(window).load(function(){
         $('.box').addClass('boxload');
});                                                                                          what I need is that this slides happend while the element is visible

Comment: Would you mind uploading your HTML, your CSS and your current code to jsbin.com? Would help us a lot.

Comment: you may find the html here [link]http://snipt.org/embed/AhgC3

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

Use the [jQuery scroll event handler](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/), to get notified, whenever your user scrolled.

Then use the [window.setTimeout function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) to call your function two seconds (2000 ms) later.

Use [element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) to get the absolute position of the object. [Related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element)

And lastly, use whatever technique you want to animate the box.

Leave a comment, if I misinterpreted your post.

Comment: you understand exactelly what I need... how do I get the exactelly position of the div when I scroll the page?